# Real polynomials forming a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vectors, change-of-basis

How do you show that a sequence of polynomials form a basis? I know that the rref criterion of a basis (no $0$ rows and has a leading 1 in every column) only works for $K^n$. Particularly,

Consider the set Consider the set $V$ of real polynomials $f$ of degree at most
3 which satisfy $f(1) = f(2)$, and $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.

Show that the following polynomials $f_1(x) = 1$, $f_2(x) = x^2-3x$
and $f_3(x) = x^3-7x$ form a basis of V .

Note: I can't use the determinant method to determine independence.

PROVING V is a vector space:

Let $f(1)=f(2)$, $g(1)=g(2)$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$

$(\alpha f+ \beta g)(1)$

= $(\alpha f)(1) + (\beta g)(1)$

= $\alpha (f(1)) + \beta (g(1))$

= $\alpha (f(2)) + \beta (g(2))$

= $(\alpha f)(2) + (\beta g)(2)$

= $(\alpha f + \beta g)(2)$

Comment: What is the vector space $V$ in your case? To show that a set of vectors in a finite-dimensional vector space is a basis, you will have to show that it is 1) linearly independent and 2) spanning

Comment: Define the set $V$, and also define what field it is over first. It looks like it might be $\mathbb{R}[x]$, in which case your polynomials would not be a basis because $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is infinite-dimensional (its basis is an infinite set).

Comment: @hardmath Hi there, please see the edits :)

Comment: @JKL I've edited the post. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @RyanShesler I've edited the question now. Thanks!

Comment: You want to show $f,g\in V$ implies $\alpha f+\beta g\in V$. What you currently have is not for checking vectorspace conditions.

Comment: @AlvinLepik Can I just chang $\alpha v$ into $\beta v$ to show that?

Comment: @Car Now it is correct.

Comment: How do I show the span? Can I just express the polynomials as vectors and then finding the rref of the matrix with columns $f_1, f_2, f_3$ where $f_1 =(1,0,0,0), f_2= (0.-3,1,0), f_3=(0,-7,0,1)$?

Answer (score 1):

You need to show:

1. The dimension of $V$ is $3$
2. $f_1, f_2$ and $f_3$ are in $V$
3. $f_1, f_2$ and $f_3$ are linearly independent.
   i.e. The only linear combination $a_1f_1 + a_2f_2 + a_3f_3=0$ is the trivial combination.

Comment: How do you show the dimension of V is 3 and that $f_1, f_2, f_3$ is in V? Thanks!

Comment: @Car Verify the condition $f_i(1) = f_i(2)$.

Comment: I guess the condition $f(1)=f(2)$ is given. Do i still need to verify this? If so, do you mind giving me some clues?

Comment: @Car The condition is given for $V$. You are not told, however, that $f_i$ are in $V$.

Comment: The set of polynomials of degree less than or equal to 3 is a 4 dimensional subspace.  The constraint $f(1) = f(2)$ takes away one dimension.  Test that $f_1(1) = f_1(2)$ are indeed in the subspace, and show that they are linearly independent.  An alternate approach is to choose a generic polynomial $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ and apply the constraint $f(1)= f(2)$ then $a + b +c +d = 8a + 4b + 2c + d.$  Or, $7a + 3b + c = 0$

Comment: @Car Note that $V$ is a subset in a vector space. It suffices to check closedness w.r.t vector addition and multiplication with scalar. The zero polynomial is, of course, in $V$.

Comment: @Car You can include that in your first post. There is no reason to congest the comment section with semi-walls of text.

Comment: @AlvinLepik Okay done.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your vectors are in $V$. There are two conditions.

1. Linear independence. Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$ be such that
   $$\forall x\in\mathbb R,\quad a + b(x^2-3x) + c(x^3-7x) = 0. $$
   Does it follow that $a=b=c=0$? Note that this equality holds for any $x$. Fix three different $x$ and get 3 equations.
2. Spanning. Let $p(x) := ax^3 + bx^2+cx + d$ such that $p(1) = p(2)$. Find $u,v,w$ such that
   $$\forall x\in\mathbb R,\quad ax^3+bx^2+cx + d = u + v(x^2-3x) + w(x^3-7x). $$

---

To check $V$ is a vector subspace, take $f,g\in V$ i.e $f(1) = f(2)$ and $g(1) = g(2)$. Check the condition for $V$:
$$(f+g)(1) \overset{?}= (f+g)(2),\qquad \forall \alpha\in\mathbb R,\quad (\alpha f)(1) = (\alpha f)(2)\,?  $$
or you could do this in one go by verifying
$$ \forall \alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R,\quad (\alpha f+\beta g)(1) = (\alpha f+\beta g)(2). $$
Either option suffices.

Comment: I have checked that V is a subspace in the post, can you confirm if its right?